# Cookies in Google Scripts Web App

Tags: session, cookies, google-apps-script

Is it possible to keep track of cookies (or any kind of session variables) in a GAS Web App? The script is running as myself, and anyone (even anonymous) can access the site. I need to be able to keep track of login information, so I should be able to see if the user is logged in between requests.

Note: The user is not required to have a Gmail account.

Comment: Look more closely. That is a Session for a given Gmail user, not a given browser. Again, the user is *not* required to have a Gmail account. I was aware of this class, but it does not work for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the GAS solution for this even after almost 3 years since this question was asked.

Looks like the only solution is to use javascript cookie handling (`document.cookie`) in each template file.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't give the GAS scripts access to the cookies though. That's what I need.

Comment: I found another workaround: CacheService.getUserCache()
There are three types of cache instances, don't know what's the difference, but you can use them as container for cookies, kind of. The only issue is that this cache is attached to user's ip, so he will get same cache in different browsers.